# perforce client spec - making different depot paths map to the same client workspace path

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I want to create a client with the following view:

```
//depot/location1/main/... //myclient/main/...
//depot/location2/main/... //myclient/main/...
```

No files and directories are common between //depot/location1/main/..., and //depot/location2/main/...

But when I do p4 sync, it only syncs from //depot/location2/main/...

How can I make it sync from both locations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this

```
//depot/location1/main/... //myclient/main/...
+//depot/location2/main/... //myclient/main/...
```

The plus does what you are looking for, it tells perforce to add the files from that depot location to an already defined workspace location.

Comment: Never knew about that syntax, only knew that you could use - to remove directories. Nice!

Comment: The thing to look out for here is that if filenames do match in location1 and location2, those from location2 will be what gets synced. It can trip you up if not careful.