# Perforce: How to remap different Stream paths to same Workspace folder?

Tags: perforce

We have been setting up Perforce in the studio, and we decided to work with Streams for the sake of simplicity. One of the problems that I have been running into is not being able to remap more than one folder from the Stream into the same target folder in the Workspace.

I know about the Overlay Operator (+), but this isn't allowed when setting up the Stream View Path. I tried to do it with Workspace Remap, but it doesn't seem to be working. 
Basically what I am trying to do is

```
Dev/FolderA/... Dev/...
+Dev/FolderB/... Dev/...
```

FolderA and FolderB have different files that don't share the same name, and my only interest in having them in the same folder is for Build purposes in the local drive.

Any ideas?

PS: I know this is similar to [perforce client spec - making different depot paths map to the same client workspace path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301151/perforce-client-spec-making-different-depot-paths-map-to-the-same-client-works) , the difference being that this only works for traditional local depot views (not streams).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The "+" lines are called overlay mappings and they can't be used stream workspace view specs.

The streams framework has several constraints that raw Perforce does not. The simplicity you're looking for relies on these constraints. The other constraint you may have already noticed with views is that you can't have leading or embedded wildcards like '...this/example/...' or 'this/.../one'.

So if you're trying to make streams do exactly what you're used to doing with native Perforce, you could end up putting a lot of work into it for not a whole lot of gain. As with any framework, the best way to get the most out of streams is to start fresh and spin up a new workflow based on its strengths.

That being said, there is a sneaky trick you can try. You can create static, non-stream client views that map stream depot paths. Any mapping syntax you like can be used in non-stream client views.

Non-stream views can be used to sync stream files and to work on them, but not to submit them. To submit files you'll have to switch your workspace to a stream client, submit the files, and switch the workspace back. As long as you don't re-sync between switching views your files won't be rearranged on local disk.

How well this works for you will depend on, among other things, which clients tools you're using. Some tools may not allow non-stream clients to work on stream files. Others tools may allow it, but they might show inconsistent states because they don't expect you to be doing that. And of course subverting the framework like this might just make things more complicated for you in the long run.